# Click event not fired when change event fired simultaneously

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, meteor, dom-events

I have a problem which I don't know is related to the meteor implementation of events or to Javascript events in general.

I have a textbox attached to a "change" event.
Next to it, I have a button attached to a "click" event.

When I do a change in the textbox and click the button, the click event does not fire (only the change event does). So I have to click the button two times for the click event to fire.

In Firefox, it works if I attach a `mousedown` event instead of the click event to the button. In Chrome it doesn't work either ways.

Minimal code reproducing the problem:

JAVASCRIPT: testevent.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Session.set("something", "something");

  Template.hello.foo = function() {
    return Session.get("foo");
  };

  Template.hello.something = function() {
    return Session.get("something");
  }
  Template.hello.events({
    'click .buttonid' : function () {
      console.log("click !");
    },
    'change  .textid' : function (e,t) {
      console.log("change !");
      var bar = e.target.value;
      Session.set("foo",bar);
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

HTML: testevent.html

```
<head>
  <title>testevent</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <input type="text" class="textid" value="{{foo}}"/>
  <input type="button" class="buttonid" value="{{something}}" />
</template>
```

When I replace class with id the click event fire, but when I have multiple fields with the same id the events work only on one field.

Comment: I'd recommend including the minim amount of template and controller code in order for us to examine the problem.

Comment: I have added some minimal code demosntrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks for including the code. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce the problem on my machine (Ubuntu 13.04) - in both FF and chromium the `change` and `click` events fire when I click the button.

Comment: Steps to reproduce :
- enter some keys in the input box (abc)
- immediately click on the "something" button
- the console shows "change" but not "click"

I'm also on Ubuntu 13.04 with stock (ubuntu provided 21.0 for Canonical) firefox.

I have the same problem on windows clients.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did and I see both events in both browsers. My system is up to date so I'm using FF 21, chromium 25.0.1364.160, and meteor 0.6.3.1 via `mrt`. I suspect there is some subtle difference between the code you provided and the code you are running. What happens if you create a fresh project and only use the above code?

Comment: It's what i did, fresh project, just to find the minimal code. The "hello" template is from the hello world auto-created stub.  I can post the actual files later.

Comment: Ok, i posted the whole files. The css is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with the `hello.foo`:

```
Template.hello.foo = function() {
  return Session.get("foo");
};
```

and the fact that the value of `foo` is used to reactively populate the text input. If you remove the `hello.foo` function everything works as expected. When the user clicks the button, the change event fires which sets the `"foo"` session variable which in turn causes the template to re-render. I think the rendering process clears the remaining event queue, so the click handler never fires.

There are a couple of ways you can fix this. An easy (but crude) way is just to delay setting the session variable in the change event handler. For example:

```
Meteor.setTimeout(function(){Session.set("foo", bar);}, 100);
```

Obviously you would need to choose an appropriate delay and that may be browser/data dependent. Alternatively, you can just put the text input in its own template. For example:

```
<template name="hello">
  {{> helloText}}
  <input type="button" class="buttonid" value="{{something}}" />
</template>

<template name="helloText">
  <input type="text" class="textid" value="{{foo}}"/>
</template>
```

After binding the events properly to this new template, you will find that `helloText` will be rendered separately from `hello` and thus your events will be preserved.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i was thinking, but how to circumvent this problem ?
The actual code is not doing somthing stupid like this, the mongo collection is updated when the form field loose focus.
What is strange is the behaviour of the browser, this bug is not happening with firefox when you replace the "class" by in "id", but then you loose the possibility of having multiple instances of the form field.

Comment: Given that we are dealing with two events and a render, all of which could be ordered somewhat arbitrarily, I'm not surprised that the results are browser-specific. I've added some possible generic solutions to my answer. There may be more alternatives but it's hard to say without having more implementation details.

Comment: Ok, thank you.
What i did, is that i placed my record lines in some subtemplates and replaced the class selector with id selectors. For some reason, the "bug" doesn't happen with id selectors.
Thank you for taking the time to help me !

Comment: Sure no problem. I'm glad you got it working. Feel free to mark this answer as accepted. :)